# F# - How to properly compile with fsyacc and fslex

Tags: types, compilation, f#, functional-programming

I'm trying to compile my lexer.fsl parser.fsy ast.fs in order to generate a .exe file that can read from a file to work with it, I'm using my ubuntu terminal and try to compile them directly with

> fsyacc parser.fsy    && fslex lexer.fsl

But is not working for me but I don't get how to use them in order to compile my files directly from my terminal, the error when I try fslex lexer.fsl is :

```
unrecognized argument: --exename:fslex
fslex <filename>
-o <string>: Name the output file.
--codepage <int>: Assume input lexer specification file is encoded with the given codepage.
--light: (ignored)
--light-off: Add #light "off" to the top of the generated file
--lexlib <string>: Specify the namespace for the implementation of the lexer table interpreter (default Microsoft.FSharp.Text.Lexing)
--unicode: Produce a lexer for use with 16-bit unicode characters.
--help: display this list of options
-help: display this list of options
```

The same error I get with fsyacc parser.fsy. I tried using the options but the error still the same.

Comment: There aren't enough details in your question for us to be able to help you. What **specific** error message are you getting?

Comment: The error i think is that im passing the file wrong to fsyacc, i tried many ways of passing the file but no succes.

Comment: But what is the error **message** that fsyacc is printing when you try to run it? Please copy and paste it into your question, so that we can have enough details to help you. Right now your question is extremely vague, and there are almost no specific details.

Comment: Ah, okay, I hadn't noticed your edit when I wrote that comment (was on my phone). Thanks for posting the actual error message; that helps. (Well, it will help someone else answer you, since I don't actually have enough experience with fsyacc and fslex. It looks to me like there's something messed up in your installation: that `unrecognized argument: exename` error is suspicious. I think your question will best be resolved in a chat session, but with someone else who actually knows fslex.)